# Chancing the color and group names in barplot?

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have such a dataset in which I can successfully figure the  grouped barplot[image] graph, but somehow couldn't title the x-axis for each group and change the color,

```
d<-data.frame(Proband_ASD=c(88,73,49,37), Sibling_ASD=c(64,48,34,28), Proband_nonASD=c(129,100,66,50), Sibling_nonASD=c(142,106,75,50))

d <- do.call(rbind, d)
barplot(d, beside = TRUE, ylim=c(0,200), legend.text = rownames(d), 
        args.legend = list(x = "topleft", bty="n"))
```

The output will be something like the graph above. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the x axis names you have to label the columns

```
colnames(d) <- c("colA","colB","colC","colD")
```

for the colors, you can declar a vector like so

```
mycolors <- c( paste0("blue", c(4,3,2,1)) , rep(paste0("gray", c(10,20,30,40)), 3))
#OR just
mycolors <- paste0("blue", c(4,3,2,1))
#OR if you want to control the color more you can set different blue tones manually:
mycolors <- c("blue", "turquoise","royalblue", "cyan")
```

and then add it to the plot function:

```
barplot(d, beside = TRUE, ylim=c(0,200), legend.text = rownames(d), 
        args.legend = list(x = "topleft", bty="n"), col=mycolors)
```

##########
EDIT:
you can also go the distance and make this in ggplot.
For that you would have to reshape your dataframe first:

```
d <- as.data.frame(d)
d$condition=rownames(d)
library(reshape2)
d2 <- melt(d)
```

and finally plot it with ggplot, where the alpha regulates how seethrough everything is:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(d2, aes(x=variable, y=value, alpha=condition)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge(), fill="blue") +
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) +
  theme_classic()
```

#####EDIT again: this opens up the possibility to change the alpha values as you see fit. First you need to add another column to d2, that determines the alpha value:

```
d2$alpha <- d2$condition %>% {case_when(. %in% d$condition[1] ~ 1,
                                       . %in% d$condition[2] ~ 0.8,
                                       . %in% d$condition[3] ~ 0.6,
                                       . %in% d$condition[4] ~ 0.4)}
```

then plot again with ggplot. Its a bit complicated to work around the problem that ggplot stacks the bars as soon as you set the alpha to a numeric column, so instead we set the color to the condition, than set the alpha to alpha and retroactively remove the color from the columns (otherwise the columns would be surrounded by frames of different colors)

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(d2, aes(x=variable, y=value, color=condition)) +
  geom_bar(aes(alpha=alpha), stat="identity", position=position_dodge(), fill="blue") +
  scale_color_manual(values=rep(NA,4)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) +
  theme_classic()
```

Comment: Nice answer +1, I assume OP wants the pattern for all groups of bars, though.

Comment: you mean like `mycolors <- paste0(rep(c("blue","red","green","yellow"), each=4), c(4,3,2,1))` for several different colors or just `mycolors <- paste0("blue", c(4,3,2,1))` to have blue throughout?

Comment: Yes, I meant just `mycolors <- paste0("blue", c(4, 3, 2, 1))`.

Comment: thanks, @Solarion for this nice answer, how can I adjust the color tones?

Comment: The easiest solution would be to use other blues. So e.g `mycolors <- c("blue","cyan","navy","lightblue")`. Also, the second edit (after changing to ggplot via the first edit) in my answer touches on this. Its a bit tricky, but works. However, the legend is messed up afterwards. Maybe there is a much easier solution to this that I don't see though.